# Store EhCache Object as value not reference?

Tags: caching, ehcache

I'm using EhCache all over the application and I have stumbled upon a problem.
I need to cache "raw" data (tree of maps and some lists). The cached value, after retrieved from cache is meant to be processed further (some elements filtered out, reordered etc).

My problem is that that I want to keep the original cached value intact - as it is meant to be used for some "post processing". So ultimately I want to store object "value/deep clone" not its reference.

An example code:

```
//create a List of Maps
List list = new ArrayList();

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("key1", "v1");
map.put("key2", "v2");
list.add(map);

//add to cache
cache.put("cacheRegion", "list", list);

//now add a new element to list (2nd map)
list.add(new TreeMap());

//now remove 1 entry from the 1st Map
map = (Map<String, String>) list.get(0);
map.remove("key1");

list = (List) cache.get("cacheRegion", "list");

assertEquals("list should still have 1 element, despite adding new map after cache put", 1, list.size());

//check map
map = (Map<String, String>) list.get(0);
assertEquals("map should still contain 2 entries, as it was added to the cache", 2, map.size());
```

Does ehCache support that?

M

Answer (score 2):

There is an attribute in ehcache (**copyOnRead**) which can be set to true for this.
the cache configuration will look something like :

```
<cache name="copyCache"
maxElementsInMemory="10"
eternal="false"
timeToIdleSeconds="5"
timeToLiveSeconds="10"
overflowToDisk="false"
copyOnRead="true"
copyOnWrite="true">
</cache>
```